# "Tradurre in" oppure "tradurre a"?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

Frequentemente ho questo dubbio: non riesco a capire quando usare "in" e quando "a" dopo il verbo "tradurre". Ad esempio, non so quando debba dire "tradurre in italiano" e quando invece "tradurre all'italiano".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Tradurre* è un verbo dal duplice significato:

> - In senso etimologico/letterale, significa "condurre, trasportare" e in tal caso può reggere la preposizione *a* come ad esempio in "il capo tradusse gli scolari *a/verso* scuola". Ovviamente, a seconda del complemento di luogo, si usa la preposizione adeguata, quindi anche *in* è plausibile: "il condottiero tradusse le truppe *in* patria". Questo uso del verbo è considerato piuttosto arcaico.
> - In senso derivato, significa "volgere in un'altra lingua": qui richiede la preposizione *in* prima della lingua stessa nei casi come: "ho tradotto questo romanzo *in* tedesco"; "non è sempre facile tradurre *in* italiano".

Attenzione però, quando si specifica che la traduzione avviene da una
lingua ad un'altra, si usano le preposizioni *da/a* e le loro
articolate, oppure (cosa che a me personalmente risulta meno gradevole) *da/in*
e le articolate: "Egli ha tradotto la versione *dal* latino
*all*'italiano" o anche "Egli ha tradotto la versione *dal* latino *in* italiano".

Si veda anche [la voce Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/tradurre/).

Comment: La tua risposta mi sembra molto chiara (grazie mille!), ma nel vocabolario Treccani c'è questo esempio: "tradurre un articolo dall’inglese _in_ italiano". Secondo la tua spiegazione, non dovrebbe essere "_all_'italiano"?

Comment: @Charo Hai ragione! Ho aggiunto il fatto che anche quella forma con "in" va bene. A dire il vero, a me suona un po' meno gradevole della forma da/a, ma magari sentiamo anche qualche altro parere.

Comment: Credo sia una questione di gusti personali, tecnicamente entrambe "dall'inglese all'italiano" e "dall'inglese in italiano" sembrano corrette; la prima è forse più usata, la seconda è forse una forma più pura linguisticamente? Concretamente penso che nessuno, normalmente, ci farebbe caso. Spesso leggo autori che, intenzionalmente, fanno uso di costruzioni atipiche, solo per fare effetto o per ricordarti che "ehi, si può dire anche così, eh! Non prenderla a male!".

Answer (score 0):

In italiano si utilizza normalmente il costrutto "da... a" ( e le sue varianti "dallo ... allo" ecc... ) per frasi del tipo:

tradurre dallo spagnolo al giapponese

meno usata, quantomeno nella lingua parlata, la costruzione "da... in" .

Invece si utilizza, sempre in modo colloquiale, la costruzione "tradurre a..." in casi come il seguente:

Tradurre a spanne (cioè in modo non rigoroso, grossolano).

Ad esempio, di fronte ad una traduzione approssimativa di un testo dall'italiano all'inglese si può esclamare: "è tradotto a spanne" ... proprio per sottolineare una traduzione maldestra e poco aderente all'originale.

Comment: Ma “tradurre a spanne” non c'entra con le possibili sintassi del verbo “tradurre”! È la locuzione avverbiale “a spanne” applicata al verbo “tradurre”. Altrimenti potresti dire che il verbo “tradurre” si può costruire con la preposizione “per” (“tradurre per soldi”), “con” (“tradurre con passione”) e così via.